# iOS white screen

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

So I started building an iOS app in XCode 4.0. I followed the steps to create a Navigation based application.

It gave me a main.m, MainWindow.xib, MyAppAppDelegate.(m|h|xib) and MyAppViewController(m|h|xib).

I made MyAppViewController into a title screen of sorts with buttons using the interface editor.

I added a new view controller and was able to get MyAppViewController to display that view 
using `[self presentModalViewController:otherViewController animated:YES];`. I was able to get this functionality to work exactly how I wanted.

I then wanted to add a new view controller when the user clicks a separate button on the title screen (MyAppViewController). I used New -> UIViewController subclass. For this one, I set the parent class as UINavigationController. As soon as I added that controller, my app stopped worked completely. When I launch it, I just get a whitescreen. I've removed that class completely and my app still just shows a whitescreen.

How do I get my app back to launching the MyAppViewController?

I feel most of my problem is due to not understand how my "main view" is loaded. Is there any /good/ documentation explaining how/why this works in MyAppAppDelegate.m? Where is self.viewController created/initialized?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the MainWindow.xib if you connected all outlets properly...